# How to set up decent local development environment for ASP.NET and C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am experienced php developer and I have everything setup for design/development/testing etc and I can develop locally on my machine using WAMP. My question is, what should I be looking into for setting up a professional local development environment for developing web applications?

I have Windows 7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My choices:

- Some editor (Visual Studio 2010, express edition is *free*)
- Datastore (Micosoft SQL Server or Compact Edition)
- IIS
- Some Version Control system (SVN,
  Mercurial, Git etc)

The above mentioned are fairly easy to setup and you should be ready to go.

Answer (score 1):

To follow up the answer from Mahesh, you can get the Microsoft products for free:

- [Visual Studio Express](http://www.microsoft.com/express/Windows/)
- [SQL Server Express](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=8b3695d9-415e-41f0-a079-25ab0412424b) ([install that includes Reporting Services](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=e08766ce-fc9d-448f-9e98-fe84ad61f135)) (and [installer for SQL Management Studio](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=56ad557c-03e6-4369-9c1d-e81b33d8026b))

There is also a [web platform installer](http://www.microsoft.com/express/Web/) that is especially designed to make it easy to download and install the components you select all from the same spot.

Comment: Also Nu-Get is useful to have. As is the VSCommands add-on for Visual Studio. (www.vscommands.com  http://nuget.codeplex.com/)